# Prove the sum and intersection of infinite sets $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty [\frac{-1}{n}, \frac{n+1}n)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Find the solution and prove it:

1)$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty [\frac{-1}{n}, \frac{n+1}n)$
I found the intersection is [0,1], but I could not prove it

2)$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty [\frac{1}{n}, n]$
The solution is $(0,+ \infty)$

Does anybody know how to prove it?

*I cannot use limits

Comment: Use the definition of union and intersection of sets.

Comment: In 2) the answer is $(0,\infty)$ (round bracket on the left).

Comment: Why is $0$ not in the first intersection?

Comment: (Following the two comments and subsequent edits, can you reveal how you found the two original solutions? These might be enlightening as to why you're having difficulties.)

Comment: The Archimedean property is what you should be using here. Suppose there was an element less than zero in the intersection in the first one, then arrive at a contradiction. Do something similar for the other end of the interval. Very similar arguments work for your second problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Let
   \begin{eqnarray}
   A_n&=&\left(-\infty,-\frac1n\right),\, A_\infty=(-\infty,0),\, A=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n,\\ 
   B_n&=&\left(1+\frac1n,\infty\right),\, B_\infty=(1,\infty),\, B=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n.
   \end{eqnarray}
   Since $A_n\subset A_\infty$ for every $n\ge 1$, we have $A\subset A_\infty$.

If $a \in A_\infty$, let $p$ be a positive integer such that $\displaystyle p>-\frac1a$. Then $a<-\frac1p$, i.e. $a\in A_p\subset A$. Thus $A_\infty\subset A$, and we conclude that $A=A_\infty$.

Similarly, since $B_n\subset B_\infty$ for every $n\ge 1$, we have 
$B\subset B_\infty$.

Also, if $b \in B_\infty$, let $q$ be a positive integer such that $\displaystyle q>\frac{1}{b-1}$. Then $b>1+\frac1q$, i.e. $b\in B_q\subset B$. Thus $B_\infty\subset B$, and we conclude that $B=B_\infty$.

If we denote by $X^c$ the complement of a subset $X$ of $\mathbb{R}$, we get:
\begin{eqnarray}
\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\left[-\frac1n,\frac{n+1}{n}\right]&=&\left\{\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\left[-\frac1n,\frac{n+1}{n}\right]\right)^c\right\}^c\\
&=&\left\{\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left[-\frac1n,\frac{n+1}{n}\right]^c\right\}^c\\
&=&\left\{\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left[\left(-\infty,-\frac1n\right)\bigcup\left(1+\frac1n,\infty\right)\right]\right\}^c\\
&=&\left\{\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty[A_n\cup B_n]\right\}^c\\
&=&\left\{\left[\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right]\bigcup\left[\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n\right]\right\}^c\\
&=&(A\cup B)^c=(A_\infty\cup B_\infty)^c=[0,1].
\end{eqnarray}
2. Since $\displaystyle \left[\frac1n,n\right]\subset (0,\infty)$ for every $n\ge 1$, we have
$$
\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left[\frac1n,n\right]\subset (0,\infty).
$$
If $x\in (0,\infty)$, denote by $\lfloor x\rfloor$ the integer part of $x$. Setting $N=\lfloor x\rfloor+1$, we have
$$
x\in \left[\frac1N,N\right] \subset  \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left[\frac1n,n\right],
$$
i.e.
$$
(0,\infty)\subset \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left[\frac1n,n\right]
$$
Thus
$$
\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left[\frac1n,n\right]=(0,\infty).
$$

Comment: The problem is that I am not allowed to use limits