# How to evaluate infinite intersections or unions on any intervals?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm having trouble understanding the basic principles of evaluating infinite intersections or unions on any intervals. Such as

$$\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} [2+i^{-2}, 5-i^{-2}]$$

I've been using the following:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1438760/248602

as an example, but I have trouble adapting this to infinite intersections since the arguments should be slightly different.

Can anyone explain the basic rules / common techniques for evaluating infinite intersections or unions for **any** intervals?

Comment: Do you have problems with the definitions of arbitrary intersections and unions?

Comment: This is not interval-related though, is this?

Comment: @Charter No, but mainly the arguments that I will have to formulate. Like how to display $[3,4] \subset \bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} [2+i^{-2}, 5- i^{-2}]$ and $\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} [2+i^{-2}, 5- i^{-2}] \subset [3,4]$

Comment: @user160738 No I don't think it is. But it's slightly different to prove when either of the limits is $\infty$, rather than both limits being some number and/or a sequence.

Comment: Is $\{a,b\}=[a,b]$ or is it a set with elements $a,b$? Or $\{a,b\}=(a,b)$?

Comment: @mavavilj just prove that every $x\in [3, 4]$ belongs to $[2+i^{-2}, 5- i^{-2}]$ for every $i\ge 1$. Apply the same idea to prove the other inclusion.

Comment: @Charter Is that enough? What about $x \not \in [3,4]$?

Comment: The definition of "infinite" intersection/union is just that $x\in \bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i$ if and only if $x\in A_i$ for all $i\ge 1$

Comment: @Charter Also, does that prove "both inclusions" as given in the third comment? I think it proves only one inclusion.

Comment: For your comment I suppose that you want $[3, 4]=\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} [2+i^{-2}, 5- i^{-2}]$. So you only need to take elements in each set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Prove" is the wrong word.  Maybe you meant "evaluate" or "simplify" or express in some simple form. One *proves* theorems; one *proves* identities; one *proves* propositions, lemmas, corollaries, etc.; one *prives* things that can be true of false. One does not "prove" intersections of sets.

As it stands now, the expression you wrote is $$\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty \{2+i^{-2}, 5-i^{-2}\}.$$ Maybe you meant $$\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty (2+i^{-2}, 5-i^{-2})$$ or $$\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty [2+i^{-2}, 5-i^{-2}].$$
In conventional notation $\{a,b\}$ means a set with only two members $a$ and $b$, and $(a,b)$ means an open interval from $a$ to $b$, with infinitely many members (except when that notation refers to an ordered pair, which is quite a different thing), and $[a,b]$ means the closed interval from $a$ to $b$.

Let us suppose for the moment that you meant $$\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty (2+i^{-2}, 5-i^{-2}).$$

The main thing you need to know is this: **A number (or other object) is a member of the intersection of a specified collection of sets if and only if it is a member of every one of them.**

You're looking at
$$
(3,4) \cap (2+\tfrac 1 4, 5-\tfrac 1 4) \cap (2+\tfrac 1 9, 5 - \tfrac 1 9) \cap \cdots.
$$
These intervals are actually getting longer, so the first one is a subset of all of the others.  Therefore the only numbers that are in every one of these intervals are those that are in the first one, $(3,4)$, so that is the intersection.

I am suspicious: I wonder if you saw $\displaystyle \bigcap_{i=1}^\infty (2-i^{-2}, 5 + i^{-2})$ and interchange the plus and minus signs.  In that case, you'd have
$$
(1,6) \cap (2-\tfrac 1 4, 5 + \tfrac 1 4) \cap (2-\tfrac 1 9, 5+\tfrac 1 9) \cap \cdots.
$$
In that case, the lower bound of each interval is less than $2$ and the upper bound is more than $5$.  $2$ and $5$ are both members of every one of those intervals, and so are all numbers between $2$ and $5$. But every number less than $2$ will get excluded by some of the intervals, as will every number more than $5$.  Thus the intersection in that case is $[2,5]$, a closed interval that includes both endpoints.

Comment: Could you clarify whether the argument about $(3,4)$ being included in all of the later sets is enough to prove that the infinite intersection is only $(3,4)$. Is there perhaps a more formal argument to this?

Comment: If $A$ is a subset of $B$ and of $C$, etc., then $A\cap B\cap C\cap \cdots = A.$  The essential point here is that a number (or other object) is a member of the intersection of a specified collection of sets if and only if it is a member of every one of them. In particular, that means that in order that $x$ be a member of the intersection, it must be a member of $A$. Since $A$ is a subset of the other sets, if it is a member of $A$ then it is a member of all of the others, and therefore of all of them including $A$. If it's a member of all of them, then it's a member of the intersection.